# Sheets API batchupdate gives TypeError when trying to change background color

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

To be more specific, I'm following a basic tutorial by google, attempting to change the background color of a cell for another application but right now I'm running it alone for the sake of testing. The code being run is

```
    def highlight(sheetId):
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from httplib2 import Http
    from oauth2client import file, client as gclient, tools

    SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = gclient.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    servicebot = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    reqs = {"requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startColumnIndex": 2,
          "endColumnIndex": 4,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "backgroundColor": {
              "red": 1.0,
              "green": 0.0,
              "blue": 0.0
            },
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)"
      }
    }
    ]}



    servicebot.spreadsheets().batchUpdate('19G_4_m-H_jLjXHKxb5Q4PyHSf1Tv9GgbQP-13F95tjQ', body=reqs).execute

highlight(0)
```

And when I run it I get the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rexfo\Desktop\autosparring\test.py", line 51, in <module>
    highlight(0)
  File "C:\Users\rexfo\Desktop\autosparring\test.py", line 49, in highlight
    servicebot.spreadsheets().batchUpdate('19G_4_m-H_jLjXHKxb5Q4PyHSf1Tv9GgbQP-13F95tjQ', body=reqs).execute
TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

So how could I get around this? What am I doing wrong in it

Comment: All args are keyword args - you use a positional arg to pass the `spreadsheetId` which is not correct. (The 1st and only allowed positional is the implicit `self` associated with all class methods)

Comment: @tehhowch Well the error has gone away so thanks for pointing that out, however, it doesn't seem to be doing anything to the sheet even though it should be changing background color. Do you see anything wrong with how I'm doing that?

Comment: Edit your question appropriately and include relevant background information, including related research and all tests/tweaks you have tried and the corresponding result. Consider using the APIs Explorer to determine the correct JSON

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, hope this helps.
I believe the execute should be a method. Which means you need to do `servicebot.spreadsheets().batchUpdate('19G_4_m-H_jLjXHKxb5Q4PyHSf1Tv9GgbQP-13F95tjQ', body=reqs).execute()` to have the functionality running.

:)